# Magento 2 : Add a new input field in custom checkout step

Tags: magento-2.1, php, checkout, html, knockoutjs

I want to add new checkout step in magento 2.1 checkout page.

After following link provided by Magento (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html) that works fine.

However, I would like to add a new step having a new input form on a checkout page. I'm still stuck on it.

Here it's the screen shot i've got an output

[image: checkout add new step]

Can u please help me anyone to do this? Thank you

Comment: Hi. anyone plz help in this case

Answer (score 1):

Magento have added instructions for this to the dev docs - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html